# SQL - Add If else condition in CHECK Constraint

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, case, check-constraints

I'm trying to set a condition in CHECK constraint. The scenario is

1. When column1 is null then no action required
2. If column1 is not null then column3 must have defined code

By example, if a student has enquired (1) then the he should have performed a action (visited as code 1 or called as code 2)

[table-IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz909.png)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[enquiry_details](
    [Id] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar] (100) NOT NULL,
    [Enquired] [int] NULL,
    [location] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Action_Type] [int] NULL,
     -- CONSTRAINT menu_key CHECK ((Enquired IS NOT NULL)and Action_Type IN ('11','22'))
     --CONSTRAINT menu_key CHECK (IF(Enquired!= null)  Action_Type IN ('11','22'))
     CONSTRAINT menu_key CHECK (IF(Enquired is not null)  Action_Type IN ('11','22'))
    -- CONSTRAINT menu_keyi CHECK (CASE WHEN Enquired IS NOT NULL THEN Action_Type IN ('11','22') END)
     -- CONSTRAINT menu_keyi CHECK (CASE WHEN LEN(Enquired)>0 THEN (Action_Type '11' OR Action_Type='22') ELSE NULL END)
)
```

Comment: Add your data as formatted text instead of an image - better for everyone.

Comment: @Damien Even this not works CONSTRAINT menu_key CHECK (((Enquired IS NULL) OR (Enquired is not null AND  [Action_Type] IN ('11','22'))))

Answer (score 1):

Don't think of running conditional code - just think about forming a single piece of logic:

```
CONSTRAINT menu_key CHECK (Enquired is null OR  Action_Type IN ('11','22'))
```

The first part of the `OR` will be false if `Enquired` is not null, in which case only the second part of the `OR` can satisfy the overall condition.

Comment: I may be not clearly explained.
@Damien Your solution will work partially, but here is what exactly needed
INSERT INTO [enquiry_details] VALUES(1,ABC,1,5,11); - Will get inserted
INSERT INTO [enquiry_details] VALUES(5,JKL,NULL,7,66); - Will throw error, but expecting this to be inserted
INSERT INTO [enquiry_details] VALUES(5,XYZ,NULL,7,11); -- Will get inserted, but this shoyld not get inserted